# Emailing spoofing

Tags: email, spoofing

I've got 2 macs on a home network, as well as an iphone.

I've got my own domain on Godaddy set up with an SPF record.

I've changed the password on my account.

But emails are being sent using *my contacts* from different IP addresses around the world.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Are they being sent from your account?

Answer (score 2):

If someone has at some point had access to your contracts list, no matter what you do now they can still have that list.

They can send emails purporting to be from you, from anywhere, and there is nothing you can do about it. The phrase, "locking the stable door once the horse has bolted" springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

What SPF record are you using? A typical one would look something like

```
v=spf1 include:domain_or_ip include:other_domain_or_ip ~all
```

Which means that messages from the specified domains/IPs will be approved, and messages from everywhere else will soft fail, which means that it will be delivered but treated as being more likely to be spam. If you're having trouble with people sending emails from other IPs, you could upgrade the all paramter to a hardfail, so it becomes `-all`. In theory, if your SPF record is correctly configured so it's being used by the receiving mail providers, they should reject the forged messages outright.

Comment: It's using a hard -all

Comment: That strongly suggests to me that you don't have it set up correctly. Check what http://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx has to say about the domain that the emails are coming from.